# Active record find error

Tags: ruby, activerecord

I have the following code to find the last entry with a column value of $site

```
record = UsageHistory.last(site: $site)
```

but when I run it I get an exception

```
can't convert Hash into Integer (TypeError)
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Please, make sure to accept the answer that solves your issue best (look for the checkmark near the answer score). You can accept only one answer. This way you inform community that your problem found its resolution.

Answer (score 2):

Problem:

[ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#`last`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last) does not take a hash argument.

Solution:

```
UsageHistory.where(site: $site)             # select all records matching the query
            .order(timestamp_column: :desc) # order by any timestamp column
            .first                          # take the first record (newest one)
```

Beware, that both other given answers will generate the following SQL

```
SELECT usage_history.*
FROM usage_history
WHERE (site = your_site)
ORDER BY usage_history.id DESC
LIMIT $1
```

Which is not exactly what you need, since order by `id` is not equal to order by timestamp column.

My query will return following SQL

```
SELECT usage_history.*
FROM usage_history
WHERE (site = your_site)
ORDER BY usage_history.timestamp_column DESC
LIMIT $1
```

Both are a single query to DB, so I'd prefer to stay explicit.

Comment: Using condition + descending order + `first` is super inefficient here. Just condition + `last` should be enough, see my answer.

Comment: Also, do you know that `id` field with autoincrement is more usual than `created_at`? How do you know that author has `created_at` field?

Comment: @Ilya 1) you've never proven your "super inefficient" (still waiting). 2) If I have a db without `ID` column, will `last` work here as expected? 3) What if have a db with `ID` column db but intentionally insert the records which will have lower ids but higher timestamp - will `last` work here? 4) My answer ***actually*** takes all these into consideration and allows author to adjust it to any `timestamp` column name. Unless you can address these things - don't even bother to reply.

Comment: Last will work as expected if the table has a primary key (which is more likely than the table has `created_at` column). You can read some books or do benchmarks - finding by primary key in the most popular databases is always faster than by ordinary column. If the `site` column is indexed, it will be very sufficient difference (e.g. MySQL InnoDB includes primary key in the index). P.S. BTW, databases do not contain columns, only tables:)

Comment: I meant very significant difference, sorry for my English :)

Comment: I forgive you your rudeness :) Again: working with primary keys is in several times faster than with just ordinary columns. About p.3 - it's a controversial moment - by default (at least in MySQL InnoDB)  autoincrement is working fine, but if you have several connections to DB - yes, it's possible in very rare cases. Also, it's the shame to use `where().first` instead of `find_by` in 2017. Summary: if you have a primary key - work with it, if you have come corner cases - use specific solutions and don't forget about indexing your the most frequently queries.

Comment: @Ilya I did not ask for forgiveness, but maybe it'll be interesting to others to know that you have it. I might (would probably) have gone with `where(site: $site).last`, but there are corner cases. With my more verbose solution it is taken into account and won't fail where your solution will. So advice (even though you did not ask for it): don't you throw words like "super inefficient", "shame to use `where().first`" and so on, *unless* you can really prove it with something more authoritative than your not-so-objective-lets-be-honest opinion. No offence man. We should stop this at some point

Comment: No probs. But you know that with a probability of 99% this question does not a corner case, isn't you? If you really think so, please, mention about indexing, possibly performance troubles and so on. Without it, the answer looks very populistic, but superficial from a technical point of view.

Comment: Awesome work, thanks all. Totally got the usage of last wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Your using `last` is wrong, this method expects only limit as the argument (last N records, e.g. `last(5)`).
You can use `last` after query:

```
UsageHistory.where(site: $site).last
```

Also you could use `find_by` with the order condition (its less efficient):

```
Campaign.order(id: :desc).find_by(site: $site)
```

Comment: shoot, I misread your first sentence and wanted to edit, realized that I was wrong, wanted to rollback back and in the end (probably) messed up the version of the answer. Sorry

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, anyway thanks, please feel free to make my answers better.

Comment: @Steve, It's just a users choice :) I guess that it is 100% right.

Answer (score -1):

TL;DR: 
What you are trying to do is:

```
record = UsageHistory.where(site: $site).last
```

Long version: 
the 'last' method in ActiveRecord::FinderMethods does not take a hash. In this case, you need to chain it with a method such as 'where'.
You can read more about the ActiveRecord::FinderMethods#last method [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-last)

Comment: Thanks - understood